# Реализация уведомлений в месседжере

Tags: android, android-fragment

Допустим есть самый простой мессенджер. 3 страницы(фрагмента). Главная, диалоги и диалог. Новые сообщения приходят через push и отслежуються в сервисе. На каждой страницы(фрагменте) нужно по своему показывать уведомление о новых сообщениях. Вопрос. Как это правильно реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону паттерна MVP. При получении push сообщения отправлять объекты сообщений в локальную базу данных. А в фрагментах уже реализовать интерфейсы на изменения базы данных. Если есть новые, отображать как вам это необходимо.